# Записать значение переменной один раз

Tags: php

Как записать значение переменной в сессию/куки только 1 раз без перезаписи?
Обновляется страница 3 раза и прилетают 3 разных значения в cookie.

Comment: перед записью проверить, если есть, то не записывать.

Comment: @K.Mitnick `!empty($_COOKIES['value']) ?: $_COOKIES['value'] = 'Сохранить значение';`

Comment: изначально генерирую число из диапазона 1000 - 2000    $CardCookie = mt_rand(1000, 2000);
    setcookie("Card2", $CardCookie, time()+3600, "/", "site.ru", 1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например сделать элементарную проверку:

```
if ($_SESSION['lang'] != '')
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
```

или присвоить то что тебе нужно. Но нужно учитывать сколько живет твоя сессия. 
Самый оптимальный вариант поставить время жизни куков, например 30 мин. Если Вам это не подходит, то поищите в сети, когда-то встречались скрипты на javascript, которые реагировали на закрытие окна.